# Spread all dotenv keys and values to process.env without having to define it one by one in serverless.yml

Tags: express, aws-lambda, environment-variables, serverless, dotenv

I am using node & expressjs as an app. I have problem in deploying it to serverless with `dotenv` (without using any dotenv plugin).
My `serverless.yml` is this:

```yaml
functions:
  server:
    handler: index.server
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: "ANY /{proxy+}"
    environment:
      ENV_VAR1: ${env:ENV_VAR1}
```

and my `.env.staging` is this:

```sh
ENV_VAR1='ENV_VAR1 using .env.staging'
ENV_VAR2='ENV_VAR2 using .env.staging'
```

I use AWS Lambda and deploy it using `sls deploy --stage staging`. So far I can read the `ENV_VAR1`from `.env.staging` by calling `process.env.ENV_VAR1` because I explicitly define it in the `serverless.yml` file. But that's not the case with `ENV_VAR2`.

My question is, how to load all the `.env.{stage}` file without defining the key one by one?
I hope to load it similar to something like this:

```yaml
environment: ${file(.env.${self:stage})}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not use the serverless dotenv plugin? It's exact purpose is what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there is no way, you'll have to do it one by one (you have to have an object with key-value pairs inside environment, but you are trying to give it a string - even if it is going to be interpreted as a file containing something, it is still a string when you are referencing it).

I'm not an expert, so there still might be some tricks.